# Adding an Image to JFrame in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, imageicon

The path of my project is: IdeaProjects/Poker2/src/poker/one

The path of my images I wish to use is: IdeaProjects/Poker/src/poker/one/images  [a folder inside my project]

I used enumeration on creating the cards and so for example a queen of hearts is: Hearts_Queen

I have renamed every image according to the enumeration such as: Hearts_Queen.png

I have created a toString() method that formats the card into my desired format (suit + "_" + number)

```
public void pokerTableFrame(){
        pokerTableFrame = new JFrame();
        pokerTableFrame.setSize(1200,800);
        pokerTableFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        newGame = new JButton("New Game");
        newGame.setBounds(70,70,70,70);
        JPanel buttonNG = new JPanel();
        buttonNG.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        buttonNG.add(newGame);
        pokerTableFrame.add(buttonNG, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //Here are my attempts
        //String icon1s = Poker.flop1.toString();
        //Icon icon = new ImageIcon(Poker.flop1.toString() + ".png");
        //getContentPane().add((Component) icon);
        //JLabel icon1s = new JLabel();
        //icon1s.setIcon(icon);
        //add(icon1s, BorderLayout.EAST);

        //pokerTableFrame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Poker.flop1.toString() + ".png")));
        pokerTableFrame.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/Poker2/src/poker/one/images" + Poker.flop1.toString() + ".png")));



        pack();
        pokerTableFrame.setVisible(true);
        pokerTableFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

I wish to add the image of a card(s) to my JFrame, how can I go about doing that?

Comment: Don't ever reference anything within the `src` directory, it won't exist when the program is packaged and exported.  Instead, use `Class#getResource`, for example `getClass().getResources("/poker/one/images" + Poker.flop1.toString() + ".png")`. Also use `ImageIO.read` instead of `ImageIcon`, for example, see [Reading/Loading an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. However I am unfamiliar with using ImageIO and getClass and getResource. Im currently trying ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/poker/one/images/" + Poker.flop1.toString() + ".png")); which is saying might be null.  Am i supposed to create a new object and set that to this ImageIO.read...etc?

Comment: More like it's complaining because you're not handling the potential exception that `ImageIO.read` throws